# what is the best resource for foundation Computer Science related Maths

Tags: computer-science

Could anyone please let me know what would be the best resource to get foundation for CS maths?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically got to learn the maths that you want to apply the computer science you learn to, like Number Theory, Graph Theory etc.

For eg. Pick up a Number Theory book see Euclid's method of calculating the GCD and then program it.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply.
I am actually looking to something to understand/ reading the symbols of Maths in  CS materials. For e.g  Automata, Lamda calculs.. the point I am stuck on understanding the explanations those have used  maths syntax. Any foundation material to clear this part?

Comment: I think you might what you are looking for is Discrete Structure books... or you could try to get see these books... http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Theory+of+Computer+Science%3A+Automata%2C+Languages+and+Computation++

Comment: By googling on "Discrete Structure"  , I found very useful resources. Thanks for your help